# regex split string without considering spaces in quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, split, quotes

```
string = 'protein219 Info=Acidfast Name="Mycobacterium   smegmatis" pcp=36789'
```

I would like to split the string ignoring  the whitespaces between  "" . I am using the below regex to split the line

```
mystring = [s for s in re.split("( |\\\".*?\\\"|'.*?')", mystring) if s.strip()]
```

Which gives me the result as

```
['protein219', 'Info=Acidfast', 'Name=' , '"Mycobacterium  smegmatis"', 'pcp=','36789']
```

Expected Output:

```
['protein219', 'Info=Acidfast', 'Name="Mycobacterium   smegmatis"',' pcp=36789']
```

please provide your suggestion

Comment: @Bergi : i don't think so, as the SO wants to capture the word before the " together with it

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `re.split()` for this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:"[^"]*"|[^\s"])+', string)
['protein219', 'Info=Acidfast', 'Name="Mycobacterium   smegmatis"', 'pcp=36789']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:       # Start of non-capturing group
 "[^"]*"  # Either match a quoted string
|         # or
 [^\s"]   # anything besides spaces or quotes
)+        # End of group, match at least once
```

Answer (score 0):

You need every thing that contains either no space, or space between quotes:

```
re.findall(r'[^\s]*".*"', string)
```

will match `Name="Mycobacterium   smegmatis"`

```
re.findall(r'[^\s]+', string)
```

will match all the others. Combining :

```
re.findall(r'(?:[^\s]*".*")|(?:[^\s]+)', string)
```

(?: means non-capturing group, making the result a plain list.)